# Python PyQt: How can I move my widgets on the window with mouse?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am new to Python. I have drawn polygon and circle with fixed coordinates. Now I want to move this polygon and circle using mouse to some other place on window. Please guide me how can I do it?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QWidget.__init__(self)

    def paintEvent(self, event=None):
            paint=QPainter(self)
            paint.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.green).dark(150),1,Qt.SolidLine))
            segColor=QColor(Qt.green).dark(150)
            paint.setBrush(segColor)
            paint.setBrushOrigin(QPoint(225,225))
            polygon=QPolygon([QPoint(250,175), QPoint(265,175), QPoint(250,190), QPoint(265,190),QPoint(250,175)])
            paint.drawPolygon(polygon)
            paint.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.red),1,Qt.SolidLine))
            paint.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.NoBrush))
            polygon1=QPolygon([QPoint(250,300), QPoint(250,500), QPoint(350,500), QPoint(350,300)])
            paint.drawPolyline(polygon1)
            paint.drawEllipse(50,50,50,50)


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
f=MyFrame()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look into the QGraphicsView instead of what you are doing, it has this all built in already.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsview.html

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsscene.html

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyFrame(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene())

        # add some items
        x = 0
        y = 0
        w = 45
        h = 45
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(pen.color().darker(150))

        item = self.scene().addEllipse(x, y, w, h, pen, brush)
        item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    f = MyFrame()
    f.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**Edit: Showing how to create a QPainterPath**

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyFrame(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)

        # add some items
        x = 0
        y = 0
        w = 45
        h = 45
        pen   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(pen.color().darker(150))

        item = scene.addEllipse(x, y, w, h, pen, brush)
        item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

        # create an open path
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(-w, -h)
        path.lineTo(-w, h)
        path.lineTo(w, h)
        path.lineTo(w, -h)

        clr   = QtGui.QColor('blue')
        clr.setAlpha(120)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(clr)
        pen   = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        fill_item = scene.addRect(-w, y, w*2, h, pen, brush)
        path_item = scene.addPath(path)

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    f = MyFrame()
    f.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for valuable reply, but this solves my partial problem. Actually I want to draw a Water Tank which I feel will be drawn using Polyline because I need three sides and not the top one. And the 'QGraphicsScene' object has no attribute 'addPolyline'. Secondly, I want to fill the tank depending upon my value. How can I fill the water tank (lets see with blue color)?

Comment: You can control the objects in your scene - they don't have to be the simple shape objects.  I would start by looking at the QGraphicsPathItem that allows you to define any QPainterPath to be drawn, with support for filling.  For more complex items than that, you can subclass any QGraphicsItem that gets you close and implement your own paintEvent method

Comment: Btw the shortcut to add a path is QGraphicsScene.addPath

Comment: Eric I have tried to follow your suggestions but I could not add my code for polyline written using PainterPath in the QGraphicsScene. Will you please send some small code for adding this. SEcondly, how to save the positions of the widgets because when I close the window all the widgets goes back to their initial positions (I want to save the new positions of the widgets)?

Comment: I updated the code with an example of how to create the QPainterPath like you had it.  As for saving the positions, you would need to record them to settings somewhere - you can loop through your objects by doing scene.items() and get a position per item by doing item.pos()

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, this solution helps me a lot to understand many things. I was using paintEvent for constructing my widgets now I can directly use the QColor for it. Actually, I develop all these items in static window and fixed my items. Since in dynamic, I need to save the positions of widgets. I shall definitely do this exercise (saving items) after finishing my static GUI.

Answer (score 1):

inspired by Eric's answers, here's some code that animates the dot by updating its x and y coordinates.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QPen, QBrush, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem, QApplication

class GameWindow(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.sx = 635
        self.sy = 475

        scene = QGraphicsScene(0,0,self.sx,self.sy)
        self.setScene(scene)

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.w = 30
        self.h = 30
        pen   = QPen(QColor('dodgerblue'))
        #pen   = QPen(QColor(Qt.green))
        brush = QBrush(pen.color())
        #brush = QBrush(pen.color().darker(150))

        # As opposed to using QPen and QBrush, this colors the periphery only
        #dot = scene.addEllipse(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, QColor('dodgerblue')) 

        self.dot = scene.addEllipse(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, pen, brush)
        self.dot.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


if  __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    fps = 50
    refresh_period = 1000/fps # ms

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gw = GameWindow()
    gw.resize(640,480)
    gw.show()


    # if the steps match the gw aspect ratio, the dot will move along the main diagonal,
    # otherwise the dot will drift
    xstep = 4
    ystep = 3
    #ystep = xstep * gw.sy / gw.sx

    def moveDot():
       # In place of the next four lines, one can have a function 
       # or a feed from an external source to update gw.x and gw.y
       gw.x += xstep
       gw.x %= gw.sx

       gw.y += ystep
       gw.y %= gw.sy

       gw.dot.setRect(gw.x,gw.y,gw.w,gw.h)

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(moveDot)

    # Comment this line out to be able to click and drag the dot
    timer.start(refresh_period)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```