# Drag and move Image of Button around the 'Canvas' PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I am making a 'Logic Gate Canvas' program where you can drag a logic gate from the side to the middle and set up a circuit, I am having trouble making the button move and I can't seem to find any help in the web.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


class Ui_drag_drop(object):

    def andgdrag(self):
        print("AND press")


    
    def setupUi(self, drag_drop):
        drag_drop.setObjectName("drag_drop")
        drag_drop.resize(579, 445)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(drag_drop)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        drag_drop.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(drag_drop)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 579, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        drag_drop.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(drag_drop)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        drag_drop.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionHelp = QtWidgets.QAction(drag_drop)
        self.actionHelp.setObjectName("actionHelp")
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionHelp)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(drag_drop)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(drag_drop)        

        #andg
        self.andg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.andg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 91, 50))
        self.andg.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("and.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.andg.setIcon(icon)
        self.andg.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.andg.setObjectName("andg")
        #
        self.andg.clicked.connect(self.andgdrag)

        ##nand
     
        self.nand = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 91, 50))
        self.nand.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("nand.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.nand.setIcon(icon1)
        self.nand.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.nand.setObjectName("nand")

        #notg
        self.notg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.notg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 91, 50))
        self.notg.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("not.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.notg.setIcon(icon2)
        self.notg.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.notg.setObjectName("notg")

        #org
        self.org = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.org.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 170, 91, 50))
        self.org.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("or.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.org.setIcon(icon3)
        self.org.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 90))
        self.org.setObjectName("org")

        #nor
        self.nor = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 91, 50))
        self.nor.setText("")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("nor.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.nor.setIcon(icon4)
        self.nor.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 60))
        self.nor.setObjectName("nor")

        #exor
        self.exor = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 290, 91, 50))
        self.exor.setText("")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exor.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.exor.setIcon(icon5)
        self.exor.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 60))
        self.exor.setObjectName("exor")

        #exnor
        self.exnor = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exnor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 91, 50))
        self.exnor.setText("")
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exnor.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.exnor.setIcon(icon6)
        self.exnor.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 60))
        self.exnor.setObjectName("exnor")       

        #canvas
        self.canvas = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.canvas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 421, 351))
        self.canvas.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.canvas.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.canvas.setText("")
        self.canvas.setObjectName("canvas")




    def retranslateUi(self, drag_drop):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        drag_drop.setWindowTitle(_translate("drag_drop", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("drag_drop", "More"))
        self.actionHelp.setText(_translate("drag_drop", "Help"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    drag_drop = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_drag_drop()
    ui.setupUi(drag_drop)
    drag_drop.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you paste this, you will understand what I am going for but I cant seem to make the image drag, I removed all the tries of me trying to make this work so it's a clean sheet.

e.g dragging and dropping the AND gate to the white 'canvas'

[image: Picture of GUI]

Comment: Please in your post only put necessary and important things, for example showing your frustration is irrelevant and you only make others feel frustrated too

Comment: What precisely do you want to happen when the button is drag and dropped in the "canvas" QLabel?

Comment: @alec Well after im able to find a way to drag the button, im thinking about making the user left click which would open up a smaller GUI window where the user can select Input A and B.

Comment: But about the drag-drop event itself, is the purpose to transfer the button's image data to the QLabel, or do you intend for the whole button to move along with the mouse (i.e. change its position), or something else?

Comment: @alec I would love if it could click the button and it would create a draggable button appear and leave the original button in the left hand side.
or make the whole button move with the mouse by holding right click.

https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/dragdrop/ -- I tried reverse engineering this to make it work with my code but i failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a answer from a thread [dragging and moving a qpushbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219727/dragging-moving-a-qpushbutton-in-pyqt).

For your example add a new QtWidget class `DragButton`:

```
class DragButton(QtGui.QPushButton):

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.__mousePressPos = None
    self.__mouseMovePos = None
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
        self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

    super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        # adjust offset from clicked point to origin of widget
        currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
        globalPos = event.globalPos()
        diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
        newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
        self.move(newPos)

        self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos

    super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
        moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos 
        if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
            event.ignore()
            return

    super(DragButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

Usage:

```
self.andg = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
```

And then make your canvas lower on the z-axis by:

```
self.canvas.lower()
```

Full Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag

class DragButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

        super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # adjust offset from clicked point to origin of widget
            currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
            newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
            self.move(newPos)

            self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos

        super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()
                return

        super(DragButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class Ui_drag_drop(object):

    def andgdrag(self):
        print("AND press")

    def setupUi(self, drag_drop):
        drag_drop.setObjectName("drag_drop")
        drag_drop.resize(579, 445)
        self.canvas_layout = QtWidgets
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(drag_drop)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        drag_drop.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(drag_drop)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 579, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        drag_drop.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(drag_drop)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        drag_drop.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionHelp = QtWidgets.QAction(drag_drop)
        self.actionHelp.setObjectName("actionHelp")
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionHelp)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(drag_drop)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(drag_drop)

        # andg
        self.andg = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.andg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 91, 50))
        self.andg.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("and.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.andg.setIcon(icon)
        self.andg.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.andg.setObjectName("andg")
        #
        self.andg.clicked.connect(self.andgdrag)

        ##nand

        self.nand = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 91, 50))
        self.nand.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("nand.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.nand.setIcon(icon1)
        self.nand.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.nand.setObjectName("nand")

        # notg
        self.notg = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.notg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 91, 50))
        self.notg.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("not.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.notg.setIcon(icon2)
        self.notg.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.notg.setObjectName("notg")

        # org
        self.org = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.org.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 170, 91, 50))
        self.org.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("or.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.org.setIcon(icon3)
        self.org.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 90))
        self.org.setObjectName("org")

        # nor
        self.nor = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 91, 50))
        self.nor.setText("")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("nor.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.nor.setIcon(icon4)
        self.nor.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 60))
        self.nor.setObjectName("nor")

        # exor
        self.exor = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 290, 91, 50))
        self.exor.setText("")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exor.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.exor.setIcon(icon5)
        self.exor.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 60))
        self.exor.setObjectName("exor")

        # exnor
        self.exnor = DragButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exnor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 91, 50))
        self.exnor.setText("")
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exnor.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.exnor.setIcon(icon6)
        self.exnor.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 60))
        self.exnor.setObjectName("exnor")

        # canvas
        self.canvas = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.canvas.lower()
        self.canvas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 421, 351))
        self.canvas.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.canvas.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                  "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                  "border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.canvas.setText("")
        self.canvas.setObjectName("canvas")

    def retranslateUi(self, drag_drop):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        drag_drop.setWindowTitle(_translate("drag_drop", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("drag_drop", "More"))
        self.actionHelp.setText(_translate("drag_drop", "Help"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    drag_drop = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_drag_drop()
    ui.setupUi(drag_drop)
    drag_drop.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Test_Drive_Fan Can you mark the questin as answered. **To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in**.